# After trying to fix the weird characters that appear on my webpage, why does the <meta> tag seem to prevent javascript from working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, character-encoding, meta-tags

I looked up how to prevent weird characters like: â€¨ appearing where

```
<br>
```

is in the html.
`<meta charset="UTF-8">`
 was the answer. However, now that i have put this in, all my jquery/javascript code seems to have disabled. My animations have stopped, etc. When i take the  tag back out, it starts to work again.

How can i prevent â€¨ without using the meta tag, or even better, how can i prevent the meta tag from stopping javascript from working?
If you need more information about the problem, please ask!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Open your javascript console (_F12_) and tell us what errors you see.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the js console? Ctrl shift j in chrome. If you're js isn't working there will most likely be an error in the console explaining why